# Trying to edit profile for two different user types in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 user types, teacher and student. I have built the view to be able to edit a student profile. But I also needed a different one for teacher. I didn't want 2 views, because that would be pointless. Now, for teacher it works as intended, but for some reason for student, the same form as for teacher is displayed... a student has different attributes so it has a different form I need to show.

```html
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    student = request.user.student
    teacher = request.user.teacher
    if user == teacher.user:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = TeacherEditForm(instance=teacher)
        else:
            form = TeacherEditForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
            if form.is_valid():
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')
    elif user == student.user:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = StudentEditForm(instance=student)
        else:
            form = StudentEditForm(request.POST, instance=student)
            if form.is_valid():
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "registration/profile_edit.html", context)
```

I think there is something wrong with the way I pass data to student and teacher and the view can't differentiate between user types.

Comment: I believe your models are not right.. try adding a field of user type to user and then checking `if user.type=='teacher':`

Comment: @style Considering I have these models: https://pastebin.com/GFHdhjzK How would u do that ?

Comment: I think the issue is you have a `Teacher` and `Student` model for every `User`

Comment: @HenryM I'm opened for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this but remove

`User.student = property(lambda p: Student.objects.get_or_create(user=p)[0])
User.teacher = property(lambda p: Teacher.objects.get_or_create(user=p)[0])`

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    try: 
       student = Student.objects.get(user=user)
       s=True
    except: teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user=user)

    if not s:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = TeacherEditForm(instance=teacher)
        else:
            form = TeacherEditForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
            if form.is_valid():
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')
    elif s:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = StudentEditForm(instance=student)
        else:
            form = StudentEditForm(request.POST, instance=student)
            if form.is_valid():
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "registration/profile_edit.html", context)
```

Comment: What is the above "s" variable for ? I get error 'bool' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: the `s` is just to see if a `Student` exists.  If it does, we provide the student form.  If it doesn't then it jumps to the `except`

Comment: Here is the traceback: https://pastebin.com/ya2SEhkz. The IDE is also pointing that instace=teacher is an unresolved reference now.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed you were using `student` elsewhere.  I've made edits - try that.